# How can access to the Facebook API if I have restricted IP

Tags: facebook

I have an app on facebook, but when I try to change a setting it show my this alert "Updates for this app are restricted to specific IP addresses"

My computer has a dynamic IP, so I probably can't recover that address... please help me to find how I can retore my settings...

Thanks

Comment: Probably here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity#app-settings-security.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and hope that they help you. And never add an IP address if it is dynamic.